# React Native Firebase Phone Auth Error is:[firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using https://rnfirebase.io for phone auth with the sample code provided from the documentation. With proper setup i am always getting missing-client-identifier error for recaptcha.

```
const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone);
```

in the app/build.gradle i have the relevant changes

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
```

also i have generated SHA1 and SHA256 and copied to firebase app settings .. even after setting up everything still getting the issue with the real phone number

here is the sample code which is having exactly my changes https://github.com/zolomohan/rn-firebase-phone-auth

Note: There is a glitch of very minor horizontal bar moves down and no prompt of any browser and ends with the error

It would be really helpful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is once you ensure your firebase settings, android app settings are perfect then do the final verification on google cloud console API credentials where the SHA1 is properly setup according to the firebase settings. I had a different SHA1 in google cloud , as soon as I corrected it solves the issue and the reference for the same is here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4651#issuecomment-808853566

my comment on the same https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4651#issuecomment-810479005